# Cut-Off Sinusoid or Sinuosoid?? - Standing Voltage Waves on Transmission Lines

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, wave

My textbook shows two diagrams that appear to contradict each other to me. Each depict the magnitude of the standing voltage waves on a transmission line. The first, fig 2-14, shows a sinusoid bounded by Vmin and Vmax. The second, fig 2-15, shows general patterns that are clearly the result of cutting the sinusoid in half at the minimums. The second makes sense to me, and the first seems incorrect.

I have two questions:

1. Have I actually found some contradiction here, or am I incorrectly relating these scenarios together?
2. If this is a contradiction which depiction is correct?

[image: fig 2-14]
[image: fig 2-15]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-15 shows special cases of 2-14, i.e. open circuit and short circuit terminations. In 2-15 b,c the forward and reflected sinusoids are 180 deg out of phase at the given distances along the line, so they sum to zero.

Remember, the plots are of the sinusoidal **amplitudes**, not of the actual sinusoidal signals, so 'cutting the sine wave in half' is not what's happening.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_wave_2.gif